# Hyperledger composer rest server logout from client application

Tags: javascript, docker, server, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Does anyone know how to logout of the composer rest server from a client application?

I know we can login by using passport, redirecting our client to localhost:3000/auth/google (for google sign in) and have our success Redirect for passport be our client application. (I used [this](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest) tutorial to set up my server).

But I've been researching and I haven't seen how to logout of the server from the client application.

Does anyone know how? Would it be some sort of request to the server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply send a `GET` request or navigate to the URL

```
localhost:3000/auth/logout
```